# A trivial SYSENTER/SYSCALL question

Tags: operating-system, system-calls

If a Windows executable makes use of SYSENTER and is executed on a processor implementing AMD64 ISA, what happens? I am both new and newbie to this topic (OSes, hardware/software interaction) but from what I've read I have understood that SYSCALL is the AMD64 equivalent to Intel's SYSENTER. Hopefully this question makes sense.

Comment: it is not that trivial...what do you mean by "what happens?". Do you want to know how it is handled or simply if it is working. Additional Information would be nice

Comment: Mainly I wanted to know if it works. But wouldn't hurt to also know what actually happens? The wiki-article provided in one of the answers states "AMD64 lacks SYSENTER and SYSEXIT in both sub-modes of long mode." 

If I had three x86-64 PEs, one making use of INT 0x2E, one SYSENTER and one SYSCALL, will they all work on x86-64 implementing processor for jumping to kernel space?

Comment: http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=48 This blog post at least answered me how the system call dispatcher in Windows chooses the entry method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to use SYSENTER where it is not supported, you'll probably get an "invalid opcode" exception.
Note that this situation is unusual - generally, Windows executables do not directly contain instructions to enter kernel mode.

Comment: Yeah, the usual thing on Windows is to call into a DLL which has the code to call the kernel.

Comment: In fact, doing direct system calls will often get your exe detected as a virus.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know AM64 processors using different type of modes to handle such issues.

SYSENTER works fine but is not that fast.

A very useful site to get started about the different modes:
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)

Answer (score 0):

They got rid of a bunch of unused functionality when they developed AMD64 extensions. One of the main ones is the elimination of the cs, ds, es, and ss segment registers. Normally loading segment registers is an extremely expensive operation (the CPU has to do permission checks, which could involve multiple memory accesses). Entering kernel mode requires loading new segment register values.

The SYSENTER instruction accelerates this by having a set of "shadow registers" which is can copy directly to the (internal, hidden) segment descriptors without doing any permission checks. The vast majority of the benefit is lost with only a couple of segment registers, so most likely the reasoning for removing the support for the instructions is that using regular instructions for the mode switch is faster.